# How to collect data from multiple schemas ? - Realm

Tags: javascript, node.js, realm, realm-js

I am new in `Realm` database, it's amazing, and I've few doubts about the relationship thing. Rather than asking each doubt, I prefer to understand it from an example. Below given a sample `schema` copied from realm `javascript` docs.

```
const CarSchema = {
  name: 'Car',
  properties: {
    make:  'string',
    model: 'string',
    miles: {type: 'int', default: 0},
  }
};
const PersonSchema = {
  name: 'Person',
  properties: {
    name:     'string',
    birthday: 'date',
    cars:     'Car[]'
    picture:  'data?', // optional property
  }
};
```

Now the questions...

1) How do i get list of persons who own a specific car from the above given schema ?

2) Should i give a `property` to `Car` schema, like `owner: 'Person'` ?
or is there any reverse relation thing. (I don't know the perfect term, I am a newbie :/ )

NOTE: Further questions can be asked in comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there are inverse relations to be defined. For that you should create schema like this,

```
const CarSchema = { 
  name: 'Car', 
  properties: { 
    make: 'string', 
    model: 'string', 
    miles: {type: 'int', default: 0}, 
    owner: 'Person'
  } 
}; 
const PersonSchema = {
  name: 'Person', 
  properties: { 
    name: 'string', 
    birthday: 'date', 
    cars: {type: 'linkingObjects', objectType: 'Car', property: 'owner'}
    picture: 'data?' 
  } 
};
```

Here, Person has cars where the `owner` property in Car object is mapped to this person. `car.owner` gives you the Person object and `person.cars` give you all the cars that person owns.

Comment: I got more information from https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#relationships . I didn't know the term `Inverse relations` . Thanks Hari. :)